# setcookie() does not set cookie locally

Tags: php

I have a script that should be setting a cookie. On a webserver, it works just fine, however when I test it locally, it does not set.

The excerpt:

```
setcookie('sid', 'nv48thnuf39sonv', 0, '/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

echo isset($_COOKIE['sid']) ? $_COOKIE['sid'] : '(empty)';
```

There is no output prior to the call of `setcookie`.

On the server it says `(empty)` on the first load and `nv48thnuf39sonv` on the second load (expected behavior). Via `http://localhost/`, however, it says `(empty)` and never changes regardless of how many time I mash `F5`

Does anyone know what might be causing cookies to not be set?

Comment: Why do you even need `..., '/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);` You can omit them, as they have a default value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your cookie domain.

It requires at least two dots (`.`) or your browser will consider it invalid, thus not storing the cookie. The easiest way to get around it is to simply set the cookie domain to `null` when your `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is localhost:

```
$cookieDomain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'localhost' ? null : $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
setcookie('sid', 'nv48thnuf39sonv', 0, '/', $cookieDomain); 
echo isset($_COOKIE['sid']) ? $_COOKIE['sid'] : '(empty)';
```

Comment: That worked great Now I am wondering, is there was a way to specify a cookie domain for localhost that will work? I would like to develop locally and not have to rely on a switch like that.

Comment: I actually use a custom domain called `dev.local` that I've added to my host files so it will resolve locally. Browsers automatically add a `.` to the front if the domain is bad, so while it may not help `localhost`, `dev.local` turns into `.dev.local` which is a valid cookie domain.